# What's the area of the shaded region?

Tags: geometry

(from engineering PhD entrance exam 2017 in Iran)

What's the area of the shaded region?

[image: Problem's shape]

All the circles have unit radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know that the angle $AOB=210°$.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. a quick and perfect answer

Comment: @rezahasanebrahimi, Khahesh mikonam